# Why I got error 404 when I try to handle stripe event with laravel and spatie stripe webhooks packge?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, http-status-code-404

I'm newbie with [this package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks) and I've some issue that I don't understand...

I follow exactly the readme file and I got a 404 error when I try to handle the stripe event with Stripe CLI.

I redirect the event with :

```
stripe listen --events checkout.session.completed --skip-verify --forward-to https://backend.bnb.local/api/webhook/checkout
```

and I have that in return :

```
> Ready! Your webhook signing secret is whsec_mSz72pL***************641iqZ7 (^C to quit) 2020-06-09 16:38:09 --> \checkout.session.completed\ [\evt_1Gs8aaLGS8l*******7PkQZPgp3\] 2020-06-09 16:38:09 <-- [404] POST https://backend.bnb.local/api/webhook/checkckout [\evt_1Gs8aaLGS*****k7PkQZPgp3\]
```

In my routes/api files :

```
Route::stripeWebhooks('https://backend.bnb.com/api/webhook/checkout');
```

In my EventServiceProvider :

```
protected $listen = [ 'stripe-webhooks::checkout.session.completed' => [ App\Listeners\HandleSubscriptions::class ] ];
```

I probably do something wrong but I don't find why...

[UPDATE]
I finally found the problem...

I've writing the wrong route. I change for :

```
Route::stripeWebhooks('webhook/checkout');
```

And I've put in the Auth:api middelware too. So I change it...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the domain you specify in your `stripe listen` CLI command doesn't match the domain you're passing into the route configuration. In your Laravel routing config I would omit the domain entirely:

```
Route::stripeWebhooks('/api/webhook/checkout');
```

You might also try running `php artisan route:list` to see how that route is configured. My guess is that because you passed the domain name, the route won't match the Host header that the `stripe` CLI will pass (`Host: backend.bnb.local`) so the solution is to either omit the domain, or specify the correct domain so Laravel's routing can handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot but that doesn't work anymore... When I change the route in my route configuration, I see nothing in my Stripe CLI... And in the spatie doc, they write I must pass the entire route from webhook endpoint configurate in the dashboard... [link]https://github.com/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks[/link] I try everything is possible... @hpar